# ASCII Value of blank character in file name

Tags: c#, ascii, indexof

I have many Windows 7 data file names that appears to contain a blank space just before the extension.  Ultimately, I want to eliminate the blank spaces, but my immediate problem is finding them.  I assumed converting each character of the file name to an ASCII value and then using IndexOf the ASCII value would find my "space".  However that isn't working.

```
        string name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
        foreach(byte b in ASCIIValues)
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        if(name.IndexOf((char)63) != -1)
            Console.WriteLine("Space");
            else
            Console.WriteLine("NO Space");
```

The output is:

```
XL .WL
88
76
63
46
87
76
NO Space
```

Since the "space" is being reported as ASCII decimal 63, I would have expected the if to write "Space", not the else to write "NO Space".  Substituting any of the other reported ASCII values in the if, gives "Space" as the final output.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or other ways to find the file names with the extra "space"?

Comment: Unicode has numerous code points for different kinds of whitespaces. Ultimately your mistake is to convert the filename to ASCII. Don't use lossy compression if you need to see the Real Thing. Also, [ASCII character 63 is "Question Mark". Space is 32](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Why don't you use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx(v=vs.110).aspx)? The string you retrieved is a Unicode string. There is no guarantee you can convert it to an array of ASCII values

Comment: What IInspectable said - The 63 basically says "Hey, this unicode character doesn't have a representation in ASCII."

Answer (score 1):

> I have many Windows 7 data file names that appears to contain a blank space just before the extension. Ultimately, I want to eliminate the blank spaces

It can be done as:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(fName);
var newFileName = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, 
                               Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name).Trim() + fi.Extension);
```

Answer (score 1):

In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), 63 is not a space. It's the question mark symbol: `?`. The actual letter there is something else (you can find its value with `(int)name[2]`)...something that appears as whitespace when printed to the console, and is not ASCII-compatible, and so is represented by a dummy character, `?`, when you try to encode it as ASCII.

You should use something that's aware of other unicode whitespace characters, such as [`char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or, if the character is not actually whitespace, do something else to handle it, e.g. provide a whitelist of allowed character values and strip the rest.

I'd recommend you read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for more detail about text encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
name.IndexOf(' ')
```

instead of

```
name.IndexOf((char)63)
```